# Write binary data from a string to a binary file

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-requests, binaryfiles

I have a torrent file obtained by using `requests.get()` stored in a string and obtained like this:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = requests.text
```

I would like to write it to a binary file so that the data within it are correct and it is valid:

```
with open(name, "wb") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

However I seem to not be able to write the string as pure binary data because python keeps trying to interpret it as Unicode and I get errors like: `"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-9: ordinal not in range (128)`.

I have attempted to use bytearray but a similar problem arises: `TypeError: unicode argument without an encoding`.

Is there a way to just write the bytes in the string to a file as they are?

Comment: Are you opening the file in `b`inary mode?

Comment: Add the code you are using

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Use `response.content`, not `response.text`.
- Use `"wb"` to open the file for binary output.

Sample program:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/image/png")
with open("image.png", "wb") as out_file:
    out_file.write(r.content)
```

A slightly fancier program with a smaller memory footprint for ginormous files:

```
import requests
import shutil

r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/image/png", stream=True)
with open("image.png", "wb") as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, out_file)
```

Comment: you probably want `r.raw.decode_content = True`, to handle `Content-Encoding` header.